# Finding minimal "factorization" of an int to square-numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, pseudocode, factorization

**The problem I am trying to solve:**

Given an `int n`, return the minimal "factorization" of this `int` to numbers which are all squares.
We define factorization here not in the usual manner: a factorization of `k` to `m` numbers (`m1, m2, m3...`) will be such that: `m1 + m2 + m3 + ... = k`.

For example: let `n = 12`. The optimal solution is: `[4,4,4]` since 4 is the square of 2 and `4 + 4 + 4 = 12`. There is also `[9,1,1,1]` though it is not minimal since it's 4 numbers instead of 3 in the former.

---

**My attempt to solve this:**

My idea was given the number `n` we will perform the following algorithm:
First we will find the closest square number to `n` (for example if `n = 82` we will find 81.
Then we will compute, recursively, the number we got minus the square closest to it.
Here is a flow example: assume `n = 12` and our function is `f`, we compute `f(3)` UNION `{9}` and then `f(12-4)` UNION `{4}` and then `f(12-2)` UNION `{2}`. From each we get a list of square combinations, we take the minimal list from those. We save those in a HashMap to avoid duplications (dynamic-programming style).

Code attempt in Java (incomplete):

```
public List<Integer> getShortestSquareList(int n){
    HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>();
    map.put(1, 1);
    List<Integer> squareList = getSquareList(n);
    return internalGetShortestSquareList(n, map, squareList);
}

List<Integer> getSquareList(int n){
    List<Integer> result=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int i = 1;
    while(i*i <= n){
        result.add(i*i);
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}

public int getClosestSquare(int n,List<Integer> squareList){
    // getting the closestSquareIndex
}

public List<Integer> internalGetShortestSquareList(int n, HashMap<Integer m, HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> map, List<Integer> squareList){
    if (map.contains(n)) {return map.get(n);}
    int closestSqureIndex=getClosestSquare(m,squareList);
    List<Integer> minSquareList;
    int minSize=Integer.MAX_INT;

    for(int i=closestSqureIndex; i>-1; i--) {
            int square = squareList.get(closestSqureIndex);
            List<Integer> tempSquares= new ArrayList<Integer>(square);
            tempSquares.addAll(f(n-square, map, squareList));

            if (tempSquares.size() < minSize) {
                minSize = tempSize;
                minSquareList = tempSquares;
            }

    }
    map.put(n, minSquareList);       
    return map.get(n);              
}
```

---

**My question**:

It seems that my solution is not optimal (imo). I think that the time complexity for my solution is `O(n)*O(Sqrt(n))` since the maximal recursion depth is `n` and the maximum number of children is `Sqrt(n)`. My solution is probably full of bugs - which doesn't matter to me at the moment. I will appreciate any guidance to find a more optimal solution (pseudo-code or otherwise).

Comment: From the description its not clear whether you mean just to look at the closest square, which leads to a greedy but suboptimal algorithms (as example with 12 shows) or exhaustive search. The latter is optimal but far too slow to be feasible even with memoization. (Hint: the big O of its complexity is a power function, not a multiplication as you have written.)

Comment: @kfx I don't understand what do you mean exactly, would you mind to elaborate on your question? I thought my problem statement was very clear

Comment: It's `Unbounded knapsack problem`, knapsack size is n and items are {1,4,9,16...}, see more about :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Unbounded_knapsack_problem

Comment: The statement is clear, "My attempt to solve this" is not completely clear.

Comment: @Sayakiss it would be helpful if you could state how exactly it is that problem (or how can its solution be applied here).

Comment: @kfx I see, please tell me what exactly in the attempt isn't clear (I didn't understand what you meant before).

Comment: @Idos see my edit to the comment.

Comment: @Sayakiss I have, thanks. But it still really doesn't resemble my problem (in my eyes at least...). If you can form an answer it would be nice - and if it really solves it I will obviously accept it :)

Comment: @Idos You may read some papers about `Unbounded knapsack problem`, but I'm afraid `O(n*sqrt(n))` is good enough if you want to keep it simple...

Comment: @Sayakiss is there a better solution than `O(n*sqrt(n))`? The knapsack DP approach seems to give that.

Comment: @kfx  Indeed, it is a special case of `Unbounded knapsack problem`, because items are squares(not random numbers). It's possible to make use of that to get a better solution. I got some ideas but I will check it before post...

Comment: Thanks @Sayakiss, it seems like you really have a good grasp on this so I will await your solution=]

Comment: [This](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM#prime14) might be an interesting read. All numbers can be decomposed in sums of four squares. The link describes (somewhat) an algorithm. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_four-square_theorem#Algorithms) there exists an algorithm that runs in *O(log²n)*.

Comment: @trincot Interesting, but it's `computing a single representation n=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2`. Please notice **Single**. So it may not be a optimal solution. The optimal solution should be a representation with as more 0 as possible.

Comment: @trincot see my attempt to answer.

Comment: Please do not use the word or the tag `factorization` if you want it to mean something else. Addends contribute to a sum much the same way factors lead to products - if you don't want to coin "addendisation", use decomposition.

Comment: Instead of "factorization," you could simply use the term, `partition`, which is "a way of writing `n` as a sum of positive integers" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @trincot's [link](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM#prime14), I would suggest a simple `O(n sqrt n)` algorithm. The idea is :

1. Use exhaustive search on the squares smaller or equal to `n` to find out if `n` is a square itself, or a sum of any two or three squares less than `n`. This can be done in `sqrt(n)^3` time, which is `O(n sqrt n)`.
2. If this fails, then find a "factorization" of `n` in four squares.

To recursively find 4-factorization of a number `m`, there are three cases now:

1. `m` is a prime number and `m mod 4 = 1`. According to the [math](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM#prime14), we know that `n` is a product of two squares. Both simple exhaustive search or more "mathy" methods should give an easy answer.
2. `m` is a prime number and `m mod 4 = 3`. This case still requires working out the details, but could be implemented using the math described in the [link](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM#prime14).
3. `m` is a composite number. This is the recursive case. First factorize `m` in two factors, i.e. integers `u` and `v` so that `u*v=m`. For performance reasons, they should be as close as possible, but this is a minor detail.

Afterwards, recursively find the 4-factorization of `u` and `v`.

Then, using [the formula](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM#prime14):

```
(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2) (A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2) = (aA+bB+cC+dD)^2 + (aB-bA+cD-dC)^2 + (aC-bD-cA+dB)^2 + (aD-dA+bC-cB)^2
```

find the 4-factorization of `m`. Here I denoted `u = (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)` and `v = (A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2)`, as their 4-factorization is known at this point.

Comment: @Sayakiss You  can post your knapsack based algorithm, I'll upvote it if it beats this. And even if it doesn't, it should be an answer - it based on a good idea.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much. I will surely look into it and if nobody posts anything better I'll also accept. Vote up (:

Answer (score 1):

**Much simpler solution:**

This is a version of the [Coin Change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) problem. 
You can call the following method with coins as the list of the square number that smaller than amount (`n` in your example).

Example: `amount=12` , `coins={1,2,4,9}`

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    int max = amount + 1;             
    int[] dp = new int[amount + 1];  
    Arrays.fill(dp, max);  
    dp[0] = 0;   
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < coins.length; j++) {
            if (coins[j] <= i) {
                dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[i - coins[j]] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[amount] > amount ? -1 : dp[amount];
}
```

The complexity of it is O(n*m) where m is the number of coins. So in your example it the same complexity like you mention `O(n*sqrt(n))`
It solved with Dynamic programming - Bottom up approch. 
The code has been taken from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/solution/).